# Netty Server - connection count vs worker count

Tags: java, netty, worker

I tried following combinations for connections and workers

- 4 workers - 16 connections - traffic flows only in 4 connections and
  no traffic in 12 connections
- 8 workers - 16 connections - traffic flows only in 8 connections and
  no traffic in 8 connections
- 0 workers (I am just leaving optimal worker-count to be determined by
  Netty) - 8 connections - traffic flows only in 4 connections and no traffic in 4 connections

My software config
Netty 3.2.6 with NioServerSocket

Pipeline snippet

```
        public void startServer(int numWorkerThreads, String openFlowHost, int openFlowPort, OFChannelHandler ofchan){
        this.workerThreads = numWorkerThreads;
        try {
            final ServerBootstrap bootstrap = createServerBootStrap();

             bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddr", true);
             bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
             bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
             bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", EnhancedController.RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE);
             bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", EnhancedController.SEND_BUFFER_SIZE);

             // better to have an receive buffer predictor
             //bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory",
             //      new AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory());
             //if the server is sending 1000 messages per sec, optimum write buffer water marks will
             //prevent unnecessary throttling, Check NioSocketChannelConfig doc
             //bootstrap.setOption("writeBufferLowWaterMark", WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATERMARK);
             //bootstrap.setOption("writeBufferHighWaterMark", WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATERMARK);

             // TODO: IMPORTANT: If the threadpool is supplied as null, ExecutionHandler would 
             // not be present in pipeline. If the load increases and ordering is required ,
             // use OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor as argument instead of null

             execHandler = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(
                             OMATPE_CORE_POOL_SIZE, 
                             OMATPE_PER_CHANNEL_SIZE, 
                             OMATPE_POOL_WIDE_SIZE, 
                             OMATPE_THREAD_KEEP_ALIVE_IN_MILLISECONDS, 
                             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);      



             ChannelPipelineFactory pfact =
                     new OpenflowPipelineFactory(controller, execHandler);
             bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(pfact);
             InetSocketAddress sa =
                    (openFlowHost == null)
                    ? new InetSocketAddress(openFlowPort)
                    : new InetSocketAddress(openFlowHost, openFlowPort);
             final ChannelGroup cg = new DefaultChannelGroup();
             cg.add(bootstrap.bind(sa));


         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }

    }

    private ServerBootstrap createServerBootStrap() {
        if (workerThreads == 0) {
            return new ServerBootstrap(
                    new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                            Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
        } else {
            return new ServerBootstrap(
                    new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), workerThreads));
        }
    }
```

Hardware Configuration
Quad Core Intel i5 vPro with Ubuntu 11.x

Please let me know if I am missing something obvious

Comment: Can you please rephrase... I don't understand what exactly you are askin for.

Comment: Apologies Norman. I noticed the behavior that message-exchanges happening only over fewer of established connections. Since this behavior was observed in performance testing, I added counters on per connection basis to isolate the problem. Counters indicate that server does not receive any messages from some connections at all. For instance, when worker-pool size is 8 and when 16 connections are established, channelConnected is fired 16 times and I get 16 established connections. But Server receives messages only over 8 connections and not all 16 connections.